# Does Latin offer a single word referring back to the preceding *two* names mentioned?

Tags: vocabulary, grammar-choice, poetry, new-latin

**Background.**

The following is correct standard English:

> (0) He read the poems of Catullus, Juvenal, Horace, and Virgil. He intentionally memorized only poems *of the latter two*.

The following uses a *fantasy-word* "twatter", which standard English does not contain, a single word referring back *to the last two names mentioned*.

> (1) He read the poems of Catullus, Juvenal, Horace, and Virgil. He intentionally memorized only the twatter's poems.

The intent is that (1) be *equivalent* to (0). 
Hence the pluralized fantasized "twatter", a portmanteau of "two" and "latter".

Using the standard word "*latter's*" instead of "twatter's" would result in a sentence saying that "He" intentionally memorized only *Virgil*'s poems.

**Question.**

Does Latin offer a mechanism like the above (invented) pluralized "twatter's", i.e., a **single** word referring back to the preceding **two** names?

Do you know a natural language which does?

Comment: Interesting question! If the list has only two names, the situation is easier in both languages. I assume you mean something like this? "He read the poems of Catullus, Juvenal, Horace, and Virgil. He liked the poems of the latter two better than Juvenal's."

Comment: I'm not sure I get your example. "Latter two" must refer to a group consisting of more than two, whereas you only have two. You would say "He liked *their* poetry better than Juvenal's."

Comment: You could also say, "He did not like Juvenal's poetry, but did like *theirs*," which would refer to the set-group you outlined in the original sentence. There is no word in Latin that specifically refers to the latter *two*.

Comment: I might say *horum amborum* 'of both the latter', but I've no idea what a Roman'd say.

Comment: @Anonym Right, *amborum* would also work, but not if you're giving a a list of ten and trying to specify just the last two. You would need more than one word there.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer That's why I said *horum amborum.* The *horum* is there to distinguish 'both **the closest**'.

Comment: @Anonym Right, right. I was commenting on that because OP had asked for a single word.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer Ah, yeah, I missed your *also.* Makes sense!

Comment: @Anonym All good! Turns out that 590 characters is hardly conducive to clarity online! :)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I made quite substantial changes to the question, distorting it a bit.

Comment: @Joonas Ilmavirta  Your proposed word _twatter_, though offered with excellent intentions, is — how shall I put it? — in rather unfortunate coincidence with an English vulgarity.